# Installing a java application on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: command-line, java, launcher

I find "a lot of" howto install Java on Ubuntu/Linux but little on the "recommended way" to install a java application for an end-user.

I understand how to run a Java application from the command line and create a script file to run as a Java developer.

At the moment, I have developed 3 programs to compare directory structure and content, search directories looking for the same files based on content not file names, and "bulk renaming" files, e.g. converting digital camera image file names to end user meaningful names - grandcanyon.

I would like to make these available as shareware and either provide an installer or "cut-and-paste" tutorial so non-programmers can download, locate files in appropriate directory(ies) and either run from the commandline or "graphic/icon launch".

So far my searches have not come up with much other than you can write a script file.

1. Is there a share/free-ware installer that I could use that would put the jar files in the correct directory(ies) (where is recommended?) and launcher, commandline or icon-based, in correct directory(ies).
2. or, write a "howto" 1) put jar file(s) here, 2) create this file with these contents here, 3) change permissions on #2, 4) "launch" application.

Thanks in advance,
Roy

Comment: How do you plan on distributing the software? Via apt? As a standalone deb? As a shell script that will perform the installation?

Comment: opt for /opt. Best place to install 3rd party software. Of course you can ask during the install to install it at some place.

Answer (score 0):

I worked for around 8 months on Installshield way back in 2004. Also tried [installj](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) for one of the Java products that we were shipping to our end partners.
But i am not aware of opensource or free Installer kind of programs. May be you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application) which has a good comparison of lots of options available